# How to execute Command Injection without forward slash?

Tags: vulnerability, iot

I have a blind command injection vulnerability on an embedded device. I have tested ping, reboot and sleep and they work. But whenever there is a forward slash in the input ( / ), the program crashes for some reason. How can I overcome this? Is there anyway i can not use a forward slash for file paths?

Comment: Why do you want to use a forward slash? What are you trying to achieve with this command injection?

Comment: For file paths. i should also note that telnet is filtered but when i tried to execute "iptables -I APPIN -p tcp --dport 23 -i <interface> -j ACCEPT", telnet does not open.
Any help?

Comment: Most likely you are not executing commands as root? Do you know the user you are executing the commands with?

Comment: I can't say I'm 100% sure but I assume it is root. But I highly doubt this is the cause of the crash. Is it possible that this is some kind of security measure?

Answer (score 2):

It's possible that a security check is removing the forward slash or you're hitting a restricted shell that simply doesn't allow forward slashes at all.

If it's a security check, try with a double slash (//). If the check isn't recursive, it might remove the first slash and leave the second one.

If it's a restricted shell, then you have to get creative. For example, try using an [encoded forward slash](https://www.cvedetails.com/cve/CVE-2013-2182/) as demonstrated at that link.

Comment: double slash didn't work. Is there any way I could unfilter the telnet protocol?